# How to express the idea of creating the story of a book?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs

I want to find the correct way to say that I´m thinking and documenting about all the details of my book, possibly making some diagrams, describing characters, etc., instead of actually writing it. Is there a verb for that? How would I say it?

Comment: *Brainstorming*, *creating a preliminary sketch* / *outlining characters and the story*?

Comment: We would say _outlining_ in almost every case. (Interrogatives in English do not begin with an inverted question mark (¿). We use only one question mark at the end.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *document* these, you would call that an "outline", a "sketch", or a "summary" of the book.  If you're just thinking then you would call that an "idea" for a book, as in:

> I have a great idea for a book, let me tell you about it!

You can also have *ideas* for any kind of creative work: movies, artwork, music, etc. -- until you start on it, after which you might call it a "work in progress".

Comment: Yes, actually I want to document it. Edited. Thanks.